# Permission Denied Creating Subscription on group root drive - Permissions set per docs

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to do the following:

```
            var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(APP_ID)
                .WithTenantId(AzureConfiguration.TenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(APP_SECRET)
                .Build();

            var authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
            var client = new GraphServiceClient(GRAPH_URL, authProvider);


            subscription = await client.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(new Subscription
                    {
                        ChangeType = "updated",
                        NotificationUrl = notificationUrl,
                        Resource = $"/groups/{CONTENT_GROUP_ID}/drive/root",
                        ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(SubscriptionLength),
                        ClientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                    });
```

Content group is a valid group.  The application has `Files.ReadWrite.All` and `Group.ReadWrite.All` at the application level, and the Grant Admin for button has been clicked.

This used to work with **HTTPClient** and **REST** with login like this:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AzureConfiguration.TenantId}");

        var creds = new ClientCredential(APP_ID, APP_SECRET);

        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", creds);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
```

and then calling it like this: with a helper function that just posts the **json**:

```
var result = await Post<Subscription, Subscription>(client, $"{GRAPH_URL}/subscriptions", new Subscription
                {
                    ChangeType = "updated",
                    NotificationUrl = $"{apiUrl}/v1/SharepointNotifications/Notify",
                    Resource = $"/groups/{CONTENT_GROUP_ID}/drive/root",
                    ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(SubscriptionLength),
                    ClientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                });
```

(This code used to work but failed at this refresh of the subscription.)

I'm at a loss as to what's different and causing it not to work.  How do I get this going?

Comment: for context, the related github issue https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5876

Comment: on github you mentioned you were using beta. have you tried with v1.0?

Comment: We can't use v1.0 because there is major functionality missing.

Comment: Why not use v1 for everything expect what you are missing?

Comment: Because that will double code for a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using and what version of TLS does you notification endpoint support?

Comment: TLS 1.2/1.3 supported. I'm using the latest public Beta SDK: 1.21.0 and auth 1.0.0-preview-2

Comment: What's the value of your subscription length?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? In .NET 3.1 I'm now getting a error that the caller doesn't have permission top perform this action, but don't know what permission is required.

Comment: The subscription length variable you are using to generate the expiration time

Comment: It's set to 43200 minutes

Comment: The maximum time for subscription is 4230 minutes, only security alerts can last 43200 minutes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0#maximum-length-of-subscription-per-resource-type

Comment: That changed. It used to be 43200 and worked fine.  This is a major pita.  We need to be able to monitor Word docs for changes and pull the content into our CMS. I should be able to just set it to watch be done with it and never have to do this again.

Comment: (Still doesn't allow it to go through) Same error, forbidden.)

Comment: For sanity purposes: is the current user a member of the group you are targeting?

Comment: It's an application with delegated ReadWrite.All per the docs. (And same user without any changes worked until a few months ago when I first reported this.)